How to check Map's generic types in java
Do we have a simple way to check the generic types of Map object.
Eg :
 boolean checkMap (Map map) { if (map instanceof Map<<LocalDate, Double>>) {return true}}
Note : I'm looping through a nested map object (Map <String , Map>) I want to check inner map object's generic types

There’s not even a complicated way.
